# how to give write acces to a file to a docker user

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a php site that needs to access local files (the `/var/www/html` folder for example).
I have the following error and I think it's due to a right issue :

```
Warning: mkdir(): Permission denied in /var/www/html/lib/model/core/JsonData.php
```

For me, the apache user of the docker must have the rights to the local file.

I tested this but it crashes the docker-compose:

```
command: chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html
```

I test the *no prod* command `chmod ugo+rwx /var/www/html` in docker and the same but in local, it does not change anything.

My docker compose :

```
version: "3.7"

networks:
  gc-net:
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
        - subnet: "172.20.111.0/24"

services:
  gc-webserver:
    image: chialab/php-dev:7.4-apache
    restart: always
    command: chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html
    networks:
      gc-net:
        ipv4_address: 172.20.111.10
    volumes:
      # content
      - /home/hadock/samus/Projects/intervalle/App/sites_web:/var/www/html
      # logs
      - ./apache_log:/var/log/apache2
      # vhost
      - ./vhost/001-gamecash.conf:/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/001-gamecash.conf
      # apache modules
      - ./apache_modules/rewrite.load:/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/rewrite.load
      - ./apache_modules/expires.load:/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/expires.load
      - ./apache_modules/filter.load:/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/filter.load
      - ./apache_modules/deflate.load:/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/deflate.load
      - ./apache_modules/ssl.load:/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/ssl.load
      # cert
      - ./ssl:/var/imported/ssl
      # apache2.conf
      - ./apache_conf/apache2.conf:/etc/apache2/apache2.conf
    ports:
      - "14080:80"
      - "14443:443"

  gc-mysql:
    image: mysql:5.6.45
    restart: always
    networks:
      gc-net:
        ipv4_address: 172.20.111.20
    volumes:
      - /home/hadock/samus/Database/mysql-5:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
```

Comment: Can you configure the application to write somewhere else?  Overwriting its own source code seems like a potentially significant security problem.

Comment: I found a solution (I am not sure about production but in this case it's a development environment), I put the folder I want to modify in the `temp` folder of the docker and everything is working fine.